# Swagger Can't check class

Tags: java, swagger

Can you tell me what these warnings are related to?

Swagger scans the package. So far, not all types have been marked with annotations

```
14:48:29,682 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelConverterContextImpl:75 - resolveProperty [simple type, class java.lang.String]
14:48:29,683 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelResolver:94 - Can't check class [simple type, class java.lang.String], java.lang.String
14:48:29,683 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelResolver:119 - resolveProperty [simple type, class java.lang.String]
14:48:29,683 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelConverterContextImpl:75 - resolveProperty [simple type, class java.lang.String]
14:48:29,683 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelResolver:94 - Can't check class [simple type, class java.lang.String], java.lang.String
14:48:29,683 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelResolver:119 - resolveProperty [simple type, class java.lang.String]
14:48:29,683 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelConverterContextImpl:75 - resolveProperty [simple type, class java.lang.String]
14:48:29,684 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelResolver:94 - Can't check class [simple type, class java.lang.String], java.lang.String
14:48:29,684 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelResolver:119 - resolveProperty [simple type, class java.lang.String]
14:48:29,684 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelConverterContextImpl:75 - resolveProperty [simple type, class java.lang.String]
14:48:29,684 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelResolver:94 - Can't check class [simple type, class java.lang.String], java.lang.String
14:48:29,684 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelResolver:119 - resolveProperty [simple type, class java.lang.String]
14:48:29,685 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelConverterContextImpl:75 - resolveProperty [simple type, class java.lang.String]
14:48:29,685 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelResolver:94 - Can't check class [simple type, class java.lang.String], java.lang.String
14:48:29,685 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelResolver:119 - resolveProperty [simple type, class java.lang.String]
14:48:29,685 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelConverterContextImpl:75 - resolveProperty [simple type, class java.lang.Integer]
14:48:29,685 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelResolver:94 - Can't check class [simple type, class java.lang.Integer], java.lang.Integer
14:48:29,685 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) 2017-09-21 14:48:29 DEBUG ModelResolver:119 - resolveProperty [simple type, class java.lang.Integer]
```